# How do I change the forground color on selected item in a ListView (XAML)

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I'm creating my first Windows 8 app, and I came across an interesting dilemma. I have a ListView and use a custom UserControl for the items. I have created a ListViewItem style that is applied to the items. With this style I have managed to change the selection background, but I'd like to change the selection forground. I have searched the entire syle for forground and changed each one, but it does not seem to have any effect.

I don't know if it is relevant, but the `UserContol` includes a style for all the TextBoxes in it and that style sets the `Foreground` property (via several layers of `BasedOn =`, so I can re-set it in the UserControl, but have not found out what to set it to)

Answer (score 0):

If by `Foreground` you mean the check marks, then you might find this answer helpful since it shows how to edit the style:
[Listview selection display with no padding and no checkmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987745/listview-selection-display-with-no-padding-and-no-checkmark/14990251#14990251)

If you mean the `Foreground` of the `TextBoxes` in your `UserControl` - you can simply change it in your `UserControl`.

Comment: I have already removed the check mark and changed the background color of the "selection bar" (both touch and mouse versions), but I have trouble changing the font-color (Foreground property) of my user-control when it is selected. I can't change it in the user-control as I only want it to change when the item is selected.