# How to provide windows 8 color theme for Metro app Listview?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing a windows 8 metro app in which I styled my Xaml listview using StandardStyles.Xaml and changed its Selection color. Now I want to alter it like to change its selection color based on  windows theme. ie) If you are changing to a theme in windows 8 its corresponding listview also will change its selection color. Ex): PC Settings. how can I get this? also I want to hide the selection tick mark in listview if possible?

Comment: This is really two questions.  You should pick one to move to a new question.

Comment: K sure..then I would prefer to get reply for listview selection color based on windows 8 theme.

Comment: These are two questions and both are duplicates actually. The answer to the first is - you can't get information about current theme colors in Windows Store Apps. For the second - you can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987745/listview-selection-display-with-no-padding-and-no-checkmark/14990251#14990251