# Windows 8 Metro XAML. How to change background of grid on hover and/or click

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I would like to change the background of my grid to white when you hover over or select it. I'd also like to change the color of the text inside at the same time to black. This is specific to one page only, so it would need to be applied with an XKey or something as a guess. The grid starts with a transparent background, also.

I'm really struggling to find the direction for this. Please let me know if you have any ideas or links!

Here's my code:

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="335" Height="152">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2,2,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">                            

            <StackPanel Margin="13,0,13,0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SmallText}" Text="{Binding Town}" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SmallText}" Text=", "/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SmallText}" Text="{Binding State}"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SmallText}" Text=", "/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SmallText}" Text="{Binding Postcode}"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would probably want to modify your GridView's ItemContainerStyle and change its background and visual states to match your requirements. Check my answer to an earlier question related to restyling items [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987745/listview-selection-display-with-no-padding-and-no-checkmark/14990251#14990251) to learn how to extract and modify these styles and templates.

Comment: Thanks Filip, using Blend helped out. Appreciate your help.