# Giving a custom color to a Toggle Switch when it is on mode in xaml?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I want to give a different color to my Toggle Switch when it is On mode.I was going through the Standard Style but couldn't find anything which i am looking for.

Comment: Did you try anything other than looking at the default styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd check the default template again. You can bingoogle it to get this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709931.aspx

You might then want to change the "On" visual state `Storyboard` to update the `Background` of the "InnerBorder" element or add another background element and use a `DoubleAnimation` in the `Storyboard` to control its `Opacity`.

The easiest way to modify the template might be to use Blend. Similar to what I have done in my answer to this question:

[Listview selection display with no padding and no checkmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987745/listview-selection-display-with-no-padding-and-no-checkmark)

Comment: How can i achieve the Background of the InnerBorder?