# How to hide check of selected item in GridView in Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I tried set ItemsPanel, Style, ItemContainerStyle with ContentTemplate, ItemTemplate in Windows Store App, but selected item still with check like this:

[image]

How to hide this check? I want that item select only by background changing.

Comment: It's the ItemContainerStyle. You need to make sure to overwrite with one that changes the Template. Check out [GridViewItem default styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709915.aspx). This has the item container style. If you use the top, there are brushes for the pieces that you can change to Transparent to remove them. For the bottom, you can just remove the check from the style altogether.

Comment: ThemeResource is not supported in a Windows App project.
GridViewItemPresenter is not supported in a Windows App project.

Comment: So, both of those things are supported. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn263118.aspx) where it explains how to use ThemeResource. The link I provided previously was directly to the windows store default styles and templates. So if you're having an issue using them, then that's a different problem altogether.

Comment: Windows 8 did not support the ThemeResource markup extension, it is available starting with Windows 8.1. Is there some other template for Windows 8.0?

Comment: The bottom template should work. You can manually remove the ThemeResource references. Or, you can right click the GridView in the designer and go to "Edit Additional Templates" -> ItemContainerStyle -> Edit a copy. That should copy the current item container style for you to edit. Also, is there a reason you're still using 8.0 instead of 8.1? And for the future you should probably add Windows-8 as a tag so people know that's what you're using.

Comment: "You can manually remove the ThemeResource references" - but not remove the GridViewItemPresenter.
Edit Additional Templates -> ItemContainerStyle -> Edit a copy - this is what I need! Thank you very much for help!
P.S. I tried this way in the Blend but get empty template.

Comment: There are two styles on the page. One with a GridViewItemPresenter, one without. Scroll down.

Comment: This  [link][1] might help you. It work for me. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987745/listview-selection-display-with-no-padding-and-no-checkmark

Comment: That's what I needed! Very useful material. Thank you very much!