# Default ListView ItemTemplate for Windows Store 8.1 apps?

Tags: listview, windows-store-apps, datatemplate

I'd like to template a `ListView`, specifically the selected/mouseover etc. behavior.

In Windows 8.0 app projects you can right click on the `ListView` in Blend/VS and choose, *Edit Additional Templates -> Edit Generated Item (ItemTemplate) -> Edit Copy ...* which we can then tweak and is the suggested answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987745/listview-selection-display-with-no-padding-and-no-checkmark).

However in Windows 8.1 only the *'Create Empty'* option is available, which creates a single empty `Grid` element with no default functionality which means everything has to be created from scratch.

Presumably this is to encourage use of the new, more performant, `ListViewItemPresenter` however I need functionality that goes beyond this and the original templates are no longer available. [This sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListViewSimple-d5fc27dd) includes details on how to template but does not include the difficult-to-recreate VisualStates etc.

Is there a default template available I can copy into my project?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a default to copy, unless you're looking for the templates used in project templates such as the Split App. If you want those then you can generate projects from those templates and copy them from the generated code. These templates tend to be very application dependant and will reflect the data they are bound to.

The ItemTemplates don't have Visual States, just the controls needed to display the items. This is copied from the Split App:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="6">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="60" Height="60">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" MaxHeight="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The ItemContainerStyle and ItemsPanel are more generic and do have defaults you can copy, but apps usually don't need to.

The ListView itself has a default template that can be (but generally isn't) copied and edited. Controls such as Buttons have templates which are more frequently copied and updated.

You can also fine the default Windows 8.1 [ListView styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709922.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for answering - these templates solve half of the problem but then there are the various states such as selected, mouseover, dragging etc. that I would also like to style - the question I link to details how you can get a default template in Windows 8.0 SDK which includes all of these as VisualState which are magically triggered (i.e. I can't find any docs on how they are triggered but the template creates them for you and they work). There does not seem to be a way to generate these states in the Windows 8.1 SDK - so how do I style the e.g. selected state? What can I bind to?

Answer (score 0):

I found a `Style` which features the old `VisualStates` for customising - see the following ...

```
<Style x:Key="TagListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
<Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionHintStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.65" To="NoSelectionHint"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="VerticalSelectionHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph">
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.5"/>
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.500" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="HorizontalSelectionHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph">
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.5"/>
                                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.500" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="NoSelectionHint"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselecting">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedSwiping">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selecting">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NotDragging"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDragContent"/>
                                <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="InnerDragContent"/>
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"/>
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="OuterContainer"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                                <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"/>
                                <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"/>
                                <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"/>
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                    <Path x:Name="SelectingGlyph" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,9.5,9.5,0" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                    <Border x:Name="HintGlyphBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="4" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40">
                        <Path x:Name="HintGlyph" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                        <Grid x:Name="InnerDragContent">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PointerOverBorder" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="1" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground" Fill="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Margin="4" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="4">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0" Text="Xg"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBorder" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4" Opacity="0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Tag}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" Height="40" Opacity="0" Width="40">
                                    <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    <Path Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="26.667" FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="18,9,0,0" Opacity="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```